# Linux kernel overcommit support isn't working properly (Cannot access all memory allocated by mmap)

Tags: c++, linux, memory, linux-kernel

`OSes:` Ubuntu 22.04.3,  Ubuntu 20.04, Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8, Fedora release 38

`Compilers:` gcc-13.2.1, gcc version 11.4.0, gcc version 9.4.0, gcc version 8.5.0, clang version 17.0.0

`Processors:` AMD EPYC 7571 (AWS EC2) (124.68 GiB RAM), Intel Core i7-2620M (8GB RAM), Intel Core i3-5005U (8GB RAM), AMD Ryzen 5 5600G (16GB RAM)

The Linux kernel does not appear to be supporting virtual memory overcommit as documented here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting

Memory is being allocated using shm_open() and mmap() for sharing between unrelated processes. The mmap() function will allocate a large percentage of memory without error, however Linux on-demand memory allocation generates a bus error after the number of pages equivalent to 50% of the memory have been accessed.

As expected, `grep -i commit cat /proc/meminfo` shows the default value of `CommitLimit: XXXX kB` where XXXX = 50% of physical RAM. `cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` initially reports the default overcommit mode of  `0`.

If the overcommit mode is set to `Don't overcommit` using `sudo sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=2`, and the overcommit ratio is set to less than 50% overcommit allocation works as expected. For example if `sudo sysctl -w vm.overcommit_ratio=30` is executed, a bus error will occur when the number of pages faulted in the allocated memory space via a read or write exceeds 30% of the system RAM. **However** setting the overcommit ratio greater than 50% has no effect. A bus error occurs when number of pages faulted in the allocated memory space via a read or write exceeds 50% of RAM even when the overcommit ratio is 51% - 100%.

**But** if anonymous mmap() is used, no Bus error occurs even in `Heuristic overcommit handling` mode. This makes me wonder if the shared memory object creates a cache because of the file pointer? Perhaps the cache is consuming an equal amount of memory, limiting the size to 1/2 of physical RAM? In this situation a cache would add no value and present this large downside, so that's hard to imagine.

**Additional system information:**

`/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax = 18446744073692774399`
`/proc/sys/kernel/shmall = 18446744073692774399`
`/proc/sys/kernel/shmmni = 4096`

The `address start – address end` for the file descriptor in the /proc/*PID*/maps file matches the allocated memory location and size in the program.

`dmesg` does not contain any message related to the Bus error.

Setting /proc/*PID*/oom_score_adj to -1000 has no effect.

Creating a swap file equal in size to the amount of physical RAM has no effect.

*Limits Settings from a test system:*
real-time non-blocking time  (microseconds, -R) ->unlimited
core file size              (blocks, -c) ->unlimited
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) ->unlimited
scheduling priority                 (-e) ->0
file size                   (blocks, -f) ->unlimited
pending signals                     (-i) ->510627
max locked memory           (kbytes, -l) ->unlimited
max memory size             (kbytes, -m) ->unlimited
open files                          (-n) ->1024
pipe size                (512 bytes, -p) ->8
POSIX message queues         (bytes, -q) ->819200
real-time priority                  (-r) ->0
stack size                  (kbytes, -s) ->8192
cpu time                   (seconds, -t) ->unlimited
max user processes                  (-u) ->510627
virtual memory              (kbytes, -v) ->unlimited
file locks                          (-x) ->unlimited

**Core Trace after a failure**
(gdb) bt full
#0  main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffecbfb148) at overcommit.cpp:101
page_size = 4096
total_system_ram = 133873930240
pool_size = 80324358144
print_interval = 4016214016
fd = 3
shmpath = "/foo"
pool = 0x7eef714b9000 ""
temp = 0 '\000'
count = 66936954880

**Here is a simple test program that demonstrates the issue**

```
// September 2023 - Gene Weber
//
// g++ -std=c++11 overcommit.cpp -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread -o overcommit -lrt

#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cerrno>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int page_size = 4096;
    
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cerr << "\nUsage: ./overcommit <total_system_ram_in_bytes> <a/f> \n\n";
        std::cerr << "       <total_system_ram_in_bytes> = total from \"free -b\".\n";
        std::cerr << "       <a/f> = a to use anonymous mmap, f to use file based.\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    uint_fast64_t total_system_ram = strtoull(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    // Set pool_size to a whole number of pages that is ~60% of system memory.
    uint_fast64_t pool_size = total_system_ram * 0.6;
    pool_size = pool_size - (pool_size % page_size);
    std::cout << "pool size = " << pool_size << "\n";

    // Set an print interval to print status. Must be a multiple of page size.
    // Arbitrarily picking every 1/20th of the count range.
    uint_fast64_t print_interval = pool_size/20;
    print_interval = print_interval - (print_interval % page_size);

    char* pool = nullptr;

    // If the "a" option is selected, use MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED. Otherwise use shm_open() with fd.
    // This is successful.
    if (*argv[2] == 'a') {
        pool = (char*)mmap(NULL, pool_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
        if (pool == MAP_FAILED) {
            std::cerr << "\nmmap pool failure. Exiting program.\n\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else {  // Use shm_open() with fd. This fails.
        int fd;
        std::string shmpath = "/foo";
    
        // Remove any existing shared memory object
        shm_unlink(shmpath.c_str());
        // Create the shared memory object with read-write access and permissions.
        fd = shm_open(shmpath.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        
        if (fd == -1) {
            std::cerr << "\nshm_open shmbuf failure. Exiting program.\n\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        // Truncate (set) the size.
        if (ftruncate64(fd, pool_size) == -1) {
            std::cerr << "\nftruncate shmbuf failure. Exiting program.\n\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        // Map the shared memory object.
        // No difference in results between MAP_SHARED and MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE | MAP_POPULATE.
          // char* pool = (char*)mmap(NULL, pool_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE | MAP_POPULATE, fd, 0);
        pool = (char*)mmap(NULL, pool_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if (pool == MAP_FAILED) {
            std::cerr << "\nmmap pool failure. Exiting program.\n\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "pool base address = " << (uint_fast64_t)pool << "\n";
    std::cout << "pool top address = " << (uint_fast64_t)pool + pool_size << "\n";

    // Use madvise to pre-fault all the pages in the pool. Passes with anonymous, fails with file based.    
    // std::cout << "Prefaulting all pages in the pool.\n" << std::flush;
    // if (madvise(pool, pool_size, MADV_POPULATE_READ) == -1) {
    //     std::cout << "Error = " << errno << ".  " << std::flush;
    //     std::perror("madvise failure:");
    //     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    // }

    char temp = 'a';
    uint_fast64_t count=0;

    // Increment from the base to the top of the pool reading or writing one location in each page. The loop
    // will fail when ~50% of the physical memory has been accessed. Makes no difference in which order the
    // memory pool is accessed, I tried many scenarios. 
    while (count < pool_size) {

        // Print status at intervals.
        if (count % print_interval == 0) {
            std::cout << "count = " << count << "  Address = " << (uint_fast64_t)&pool[count] << "\n";
        }

        // Doesn't matter if the address is read or written. Either one faults the page. Back trace of the core
        // dump shows count = ~50% of the amount of physical memory.
        // pool[count] = temp;
        temp = pool[count];

    count += page_size;
    }

    std::cout << "Success!  temp = " << temp << "\n";
}
```